# Prevent delete and allow update

Tags: excel, vba

In my excel worksheet I don't want to delete and insert row or columns and it allows edit.

i am using this line of code

```
Application.CommandBars("Cell").Enabled = False
```

but it's allowed to delete a row

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this to disable the "delete row/col": http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1821-excel-prevent-deleting-rows.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to disable 'insert' also

Comment: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/MS_Office/Excel/Q_28185598.html